# How to use REST API to POST using Java for Jenkins

Tags: java, rest, post, jenkins

I am a new learner in java space. I need to create jenkins job using REST API. I am able to connect to Jenkins and list all jobs in it(GET method). I want to know how do I post to it.

My plan is to create a json file with input data to create job and java program will read it(json file) and post it to Jenkins and create job. I searched little bit about post. I could get few examples where some String data is posted. How do I post json file data to Jenkins and also it creates a job in Jenkins?

Can I get a small code snippet so that I can refer it or a sample Java program?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see the [Jenkins API](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API) page. You can fill in the gaps using the documentation provided by Jenkins itself; for example, http://JENKINS_HOST/api will give you the URL for creating a job and http://JENKINS_HOST/job/JOBNAME/api will give you the URL to trigger a build.

After this you can use Java and Jersey to create a rest client.

Declares jersey-client in your maven pom

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
</dependency>
```

And then create client with the code above example:

```
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;

public class JerseyClientPost {

public static void main(String[] args) {

  try {

    Client client = Client.create();

    WebResource webResource = client
       .resource("http://JENKINS_HOST/job/JOBNAME/api");

    String input = "{\"key1\":\"value1\",\"key2\":\"value2\"}";

    ClientResponse response = webResource.type("application/json")
       .post(ClientResponse.class, input);

    if (response.getStatus() != 201) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
             + response.getStatus());
    }

    System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
    String output = response.getEntity(String.class);
    System.out.println(output);

  } catch (Exception e) {

    e.printStackTrace();

  }

 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Joao. I will check the links.

Comment: I am not able to reach the links you have mentioned for JENKINS_HOST ( http://JENKINS_HOST)

Comment: Hello Raji. The only link you can reach is the Jenkins API link. The others are automatically created by stack over flow but there are not really links. If my answer is usefull for you please aproove it. Tks